# My computer resets when I try to install Windows 7 (USB/DVD)

Tags: windows-7, installation, dvd, usb-flash-drive, reboot

I had a troublesome program starting up when Windows 7 was starting, and I had no way to remove it, because I couldn't log in to Windows. Not even safe mode.

But I used [Hiren's BootCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiren%27s_BootCD) to edit the registry to stop that software from starting up... But my efforts were not useful as Windows kept on going to an ultimate freeze just before the login screen should have been shown.

And it just freezes, and I cannot do anything.

So I decided: To heck with it. I now want to format the disk and reinstall a fresh copy of Windows 7. But now regardless of the USB or DVD I use to boot the setup, it loads fine till you see the animating Windows and it just resets the laptop! Just plain resets!

Hiren's Boot CD and Mini XP, strange enough, still works :(

What might be causing the laptop to reset in Windows 7 setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the make/model of the laptop you are trying to install to? What type of Windows 7 install DVD are you using? Home Premium, <strike>Business</strike>(oopsie) Professional, Ultimate? Upgrade, retail, or OEM? 32 or 64 bit?

And what exactly is the problem? Are you saying you cannot boot the Windows 7 install DVD to the point where you can reformat your drive/partition and begin the install? Or are you having problems during the install or after the install completes?

---

> It is a HP HDX 16t

OK, nothing too strange then. Should work. Of course, I believe you'll have to a clean install because I don't think you can upgrade Vista Home to Windows 7 Professional. (Stupid, I know, but Microsoft makes the rules.)

> Windows 7 Professional x86 (32 bit) I got the ISO from MSDN Academic Alliance

OK, that adds a twist to it. I had assumed you were using a retail pressed DVD of some sort. If you burned your own ISO there is the possibility that it is just a bad burn or some other error.

You should verify that your install media is OK. I suggest you find another PC and try booting your Win 7 install on it. If you can't, then I'd suspect a bad copy of the install disc.

Comment: It is a HP HDX 16t
Windows 7 Professional x86 (32 bit)

I got the ISO from MSDN Academic Alliance

And yes i cannot boot the Windows 7 install DVD or USB to the point where i can reformat my drive and begin the install. I don't even see the "Install Now" button. It just resets (restart) the laptop!

Comment: I tried several DVD's and i even tried booting from USB... Still the same problem :( And it cannot actually be any other problem as i'm running MiniXP booted from Hirens Boot Disk and it is running very fine for about 2 hours now. Im backing up everything in my D: drive now to another computer.